# How to attach a source to an Android-Library for JUnit-testing in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, junit, android-library

I've been working on getting unit testing to work with a custom Android library. I've followed the first suggestion from [this Android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#testing) and created an Android app project that depends on the library (via Properties->Android->Library->Add...) as liaison to the actual testing project.

All seemed to work fine, but then I encountered my first run-time-exception in one of my test cases. When I wanted to fix the code in my library, I found, that double-clicking any item in the JUnit test panel would open a .class file, instead of the corresponding .java file. So editing the code is not possible, until I've crawled though the package hierarchy and grabbed the .java file manually.

Also, the debugger/test-runner is happily ignoring any breakpoints in the library. Is there a way to make the test project realize, that the code for the library is right there in the workspace? Not having the abilities to debug using breakpoints and jumping from a stack trace into the code are big productivity bummers.

**Addendum:** After leaving Eclipse and starting another session, now breakpoints seem to be respected. However, the debug-perspective will open the .class files instead of the corresponding .java files.